# encontrar elementos padre dentro de un iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buen dia, tengo un documento con la siguiente estructura:

```
<div id=’Prueba’>
<iframe id=’myiframe1’>
    <div id=’div_Actual’></div>
</iframe>
</div>
```

quiero saber si desde la pagina html que esta en el iframe, puedo acceder al elemento div con id='Prueba' esto para cambiarle el tamaño al elemento que quiero o manipularlo con css,
he intentado con jquery de la siguiente manera pero no me da resultado:
     $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener el objeto del cuerpo de tu padre, puedes hacer esto:

```
var parentBody = window.parent.document.body
```

Si está en el mismo dominio que su iframe desde donde ejecuta el código, una vez que lo tenga, puede usar el javascript en ese objeto:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById("ContainingiFrame").style.height = "400px";
```

o con jQuery:

```
$("#ContainingiFrame", parentBody).height("400");
```

Aquí hay un artículo sobre cómo cambiar el tamaño de un iframe desde dentro del iframe con código de ejemplo: http://www.pither.com/articles/2010/11/12/resize-iframe-from-within

Y, una pregunta / respuesta relacionada sobre el cambio de tamaño de un iframe basado en su propio contenido: [Cambiar el tamaño de un iframe basado en el contenido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content)

**Fuente:** Esta respuesta es una traducción de [Recuperando el iframe padre de un documento en jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114243/retrieving-a-documents-parent-iframe-in-jquery)